# Bootstrap tooltip is flickering, doesn't close on mouseout, duplicate entries are not triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/ov7qhmkt/

The problems:

1. **Flickering** - Try to hover with your mouse slowly over the images, you will notice that sometimes it flickers/renders the tooltip box 2-3 times. *Seems to be related to the `class="me-1"` that adds a small `margin-right` to the images in the `each()` function when you move your mouse from right to left on the images.*
2. **Doesn't close on mouseout** - Try to hover over all of the images faster, you will notice that the tooltip boxes are still open even though the mouse is not hovering over them.
3. **Duplicate entries not rendering** - As you can see, the third and fourth rows are identical. Try to hover over the first row one by one, it will render correctly. Now hover over the fourth row, you will notice that the tooltip is not rendering at all for them.

I have played with the code but nothing seems to be solving the issues I'm having. I tried something like this without any luck:

```
$(".hover-tooltip").mouseleave(function(){
    const tooltipEl = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance($(this));
    tooltipEl.hide();
});
```

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

**Full code:**

```js
var hoverData = [];

$('.hover-tooltip').each(function() {
  $(this).prepend('<img class="me-1" src="https://mmotimer.com/aoc/images/' + $(this).data('hover-id') + '.webp" height="' + $(this).data('hover-size') + '" width="' + $(this).data('hover-size') + '">');
});

async function userAction(id) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${'https://mmotimer.com/aoc/?id='}${id}`);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}

$(".hover-tooltip").mouseover(function() {
  var i;
  var hoverDataFoundAtIndex = null;

  for (i = 0; i < hoverData.length; i++) {
    if (hoverData[i]['id'] == $(this).data('hover-id')) {
      hoverDataFoundAtIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (hoverDataFoundAtIndex === null) {
    userAction($(this).data('hover-id')).then(v => {
      hoverData.push({
        id: $(this).data('hover-id'),
        data: v
      });
      hoverDataFoundAtIndex = hoverData.length - 1;

      const tooltipEl = bootstrap.Tooltip.getOrCreateInstance($(this));
      tooltipEl.setContent({
        '.tooltip-inner': '<i>' + hoverData[hoverDataFoundAtIndex]['data']['data'] + '</i>'
      });
      tooltipEl.show();
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="10001"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="10002"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="10003"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="10004"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="10005"></div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="20001"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="20002"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="20003"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="20004"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="20005"></div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30001"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30002"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30003"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30004"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30005"></div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30001"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30002"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30003"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30004"></div>
  <div class="hover-tooltip" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" data-bs-title="Loading skill data..." data-bs-html="true" data-hover-size="35" data-hover-id="30005"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not just show us a tiny snippet of code, and dump the majority of _relevant_ information on external platforms. A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question.

Comment: And I doubt that you are using BS 4 and 5 simultaneously, so please tag this with the _appropriate_ version, instead of multiple different ones.

Comment: @CBroe added full code

Comment: _"Seems to be related to the class="me-1" that adds a small margin-right"_ - try and make that a padding instead of a margin.

Comment: _"Duplicate entries not rendering"_ - that probably has to do with the fact that you are using the same `data-hover-id` values in both rows. Your `hoverDataFoundAtIndex` is of course going to be incorrect, when you hover over an element in the fourth row, but then take the _first_ entry in `hoverData` that has that ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".hover-tooltip").hover(function(){
        var i;
        var hoverDataFoundAtIndex = null;

        for(i = 0; i < hoverData.length; i++) {
            if(hoverData[i]['id'] == $(this).data('hover-id')) {
                hoverDataFoundAtIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        const tooltipEl = bootstrap.Tooltip.getOrCreateInstance($(this));
    
        if(hoverDataFoundAtIndex === null) {
            userAction($(this).data('hover-id')).then(v => {
                hoverData.push({id: $(this).data('hover-id'), data: v});
                hoverDataFoundAtIndex = hoverData.length - 1;
                
                tooltipEl.setContent({ '.tooltip-inner': '<i>' + hoverData[hoverDataFoundAtIndex]['data']['data']  + '</i>' });
                tooltipEl.show();
            })
        } else {
                tooltipEl.setContent({ '.tooltip-inner': '<i>' + hoverData[hoverDataFoundAtIndex]['data']['data']  + '</i>' });
                tooltipEl.show();
        }
    });
```